# Get number of pages for printing from Excel Interopb

Tags: c#, ms-office, excel-2007

How can I programatically retrieve the number of pages a workbook or worksheet will print to from the Excel 2007 Interop ([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28office.11%29.aspx))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you looking for `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count`?

Comment: ActiveSheet is of type object, what do I need to cast it to?

Comment: ActiveSheet is an instance of the `WorkSheet` class & refers to the current worksheet the user is on.

Answer (score 0):

PageSetup.Pages.Count will give the correct answer. But how to fetch the correct count if comments are printed at end of sheet.

Answer (score -1):

Just use

**"ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False"**

Change "From" and "To" to your pages.