# How can you programmatically retrieve the number of pages in an Excel worksheet?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop, worksheet

I'm not looking for the number of worksheets. I'm looking for the total number of pages within each Worksheet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get number of pages for printing from Excel Interopb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751468/get-number-of-pages-for-printing-from-excel-interopb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is how you can get it

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751468/get-number-of-pages-for-printing-from-excel-interopb   @John Smith